# Ordering of object files and libraries in static linking

Tags: c, gcc, linker, static-linking

I've created a simple static library `libvec.a` with AR tool from simple `addv.o` and `multo.o`. The object file `addv.o` contains 1 function symbol (`addvec`) and `multo.o` contains 1 function (`multvec`). I have also written a simple program to test it (`driver.c` which adds 2 vectors and uses `addvec` function from the library; also it has included `vector.h` that defines the function prototypes).  And then  I compiled it with

```
gcc -static driver.o ./libvec.a
```

and everything went okay. But at first I tried to compile it with

```
gcc -static ./libvec.a driver.o
```

and I got an error:

```
undefined reference to 'addvec'
```

I'm wondering why I got an error when I specified the library first? Should the ordering matter?

Comment: Yes the order matters, because when the linker sees the `./libvec.a` library first it will not find anything that references the functions in that library so nothing from the library will be loaded. If A depends on B, B must always come after A on the command line when linking.

Comment: If you're using gcc and ld, you can generally link successfully by listing your objects *first* before libs, and then your libs in most-to-least dependent order. For some implementations the latter is a poorly documented requirement, for others it makes little difference.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Always link object files before libraries, period.

The trouble is that the linker scans the library, and it is looking for `main()`.  It doesn't find it, so it doesn't pull anything out of the library.  Then it scans `driver.o`, finds what is looking for, but not the things that were in `libvec.a` (which it has forgotten about as they weren't relevant).  So, the functions from `libvec.a` are unsatisfied references — and the linking fails.

Note that 'object files before libraries' works when linking with static libraries or shared libraries.